# Update rowstyleselector based on propertychange

Tags: wpf, datagrid, code-behind, ivalueconverter

I am using RowStyleSelector to color my Datagridrow based on the item. It works fine when the row are drawn, though it does not get triggered when the property changed on the item. The value of the item is shown in the datagrid on change thanks to inotifyPropertyChange.

```
ListViewFileList.RowStyleSelector= new ErrorStyleSelector();
enter code here
private class ErrorStyleSelector : StyleSelector
    {
        public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is myFile)
            {
                if ((item as myFile).ErrorStatus.IsErrorfile())
                {
                    Style st = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
                    st.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
                    return st;}
}
}
```

I would like to trigger the RowStyleSelector on item change. Without using xaml.

**EDIT**

I ended up using `IvalueConverter`

```
Style st = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));

        DataTrigger tig = new DataTrigger()
        {
            Binding = new Binding(nameof(myFile.ErrorStatus))
            {
                Converter = new ConverterError(),
            }               
        };

        st.Triggers.Add(tig);
        ListViewFileList.RowStyle = st;

private class ConverterError : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            TRCFile obj = value as myError;
            if (obj!= null && othercondition)
            {
                Style st = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));                   
                return st;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you should do is have 2 styles, one normal and one error.  Then instead of changing the style, replace one style with the other in the DataGridRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StyleSelector` won't create a new style when a `PropertyChanged` event is raised.

You should make `IsErrorfile()` a public property and bind to it using a `DataTrigger` in the `Style`:

```
myFile myFile = item as myFile;
if(myFile != null)
{
    Style st = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
    DataTrigger dataTrigger = new DataTrigger()
    {
        Binding = new Binding("ErrorStatus.IsErrorfile"),
        Value = true
    };
    dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
    st.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);
    return st;
}
```